# Determining Range

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, limits, normal-distribution

$X_i\sim^{iid}N(0,1);\quad i=1,2$

so $x_i$ ranges from  $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Now $Y=X_1^2+X_2^2$

so $y$ ranges from  $0$ to $\infty$.

But how $Z=X_2$ is ranges from ($-\sqrt y$) to $\sqrt y$ ?

Comment: Or in other words, $X_2^2 \le Y$.  Look at your equations; why would this be true?

Comment: You mean $X_2|Y$?

Comment: @Michael is that since $X_2^2\leq Y$ so $Z^2\leq Y$ .Hence $Z\leq \pm\sqrt Y$ or $-\sqrt Y\leq Z\leq \sqrt Y$?

Comment: Why does $Y=X_1^2+X_2^2$ mean that $X_2^2\le Y$?

Comment: @Michael since $X_1$ ranges from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ so $X_1^2$ ranges from $0$ to $\infty$. and we have $Y=X_1^2+X_2^2$ . If $X_1^2=0$ then $Y=X_2^2$ and if $X_1^2\geq 0$ then $Y\geq X_2^2$